# Config is broken when I use load-user-file

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-babel

This is my config for org-babel:

```
(use-package org
  :mode (("\\.org$" . org-mode))
  :ensure org-plus-contrib  
   :config
    (org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages
                           '((emacs-lisp . t)         
                             (python . t)             
                             (shell . t)              
                             (jupyter . t))))
```

It works when it is located in my `init.el`. However when I relocate it in another file `org.el` and load it in `init.el` with:
`(load-user-file "org.el")`
I have got the error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: org-src-lang-modes
```

Also I have the line
`;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-` and the same encoding in both files (`init.el`,`org.el`).
So, could you explain me what happens?

UPDATE.

Just for clarification this is my `load-user-file` :

```
(defun load-user-file (file)
  (interactive "f")
  "Load a file in current user's configuration directory"
  (load-file (expand-file-name file user-init-dir)))
```

Comment: `org.el` is a bad name: it conflicts with the `org.el` that is part of Org mode proper. Choose a different name for your file.

Comment: Is `load-user-file` a thing? I've only see `load-file`.

Comment: @NickD your comment has solved my problem. If you edit your comment as answer I will close the issue.

Comment: @ChrisClark could you clarify your question?

Comment: @ChrisClark refers to this line in your question: `...with:  (load-user-file "org.el") I have got the error:...` and he is (correctly I think) wondering about that `load-user-file`: standard emacs only provides `load-file` so this is either a typo or you are using some non-standard package that defines `load-user-file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `org.el` is a bad name for your file, because it conflicts with the `org.el` file that is part of Org mode. When emacs is asked to load `org.el`, which one will be loaded is determined by how emacs's `load-path` variable is defined, but in any case you will not be able to load *both*, so either your functionality will be missing or Org mode might be broken.

The solution is to rename your file to a unique name that will not cause a conflict.